# How to prevent dangrous HTML input with PHP using Summernote?

Tags: php, html, summernote

I recently discovered Summernote and it seems it is a decent application, although I have stumbled upon a problem.

You are able to when you go into your source code add malicious HTML code like for example:

```
<plaintext>
<script>
```

So how can I prevent that using PHP? I do want users to be able to use certain style tags like for example:

```
<h1>
<p>
```

Which the editor uses automatically.

I know I can go ahead and use str_replace() to check if the string has any of the malicious HTML in it, but I figured there must be an easier way to do it.

Comment: [Solution](http://parsedown.org/): Use [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/) or you could use [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) optional parameter to specify tags you want, the rest will be stripped.

Comment: I do want that people can say <plaintext>, only the < & > in that case should be translated to their ascii codes or whatever it is called. So not stripped, just replaced with safe text and only if it is malicious.

Comment: I do believe you are looking for [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), though I am unsure how you'd go about applying to individual malicious tags.

Comment: @Script47 That does indeed work, although it applies to every tag, which messes up if the user for example wants to use the <b> tag.

Comment: Which is why my first comment suggested a tag-less solution, saves you a lot of hassle trying to filter out the malicious tags.

Comment: Although with that I would need to look for every tag that I want to allow, so that is why I was asking if there was maybe an easier way to do that.

Comment: I mean't the part before I suggested `strip_tags`.

Comment: That would mean that I have to rewrite how Summernote works and I have no clue how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the problem here is that you're using text in the context of HTML without escaping all the reserved entities properly, which can lead to the injection of arbitrary HTML like you describe.  `htmlspecialchars()` is the normal solution for this problem.

However, you want to support HTML, but don't really want to support all of it.  Therefore, you need a different solution entirely.  [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) is one solution that does what you want.  It parses the data and only passes through white-listed tags.  From their [documentation](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs):

```
require_once '/path/to/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';

$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
$clean_html = $purifier->purify($dirty_html);
```

Comment: The problem with that is that it completely removed <plaintext> and other malicious HTML, I want the malicious HTML to be converted to safe HTML.

Comment: I also just found out that the HTML Purifier doesn't support HTML 5, so although it does work it does let some tags through which might be malicious.

Comment: You get to specify a white list of what you want to keep. And, I doubt it's letting anything malicious through. Have you tired it? Make a bug report if so.

Comment: I am going to mark this as the answer due to it working. I also found a HTML 5 library over here: https://github.com/kennberg/php-htmlpurfier-html5 So hopefully that is enough. Thanks.